# Pakistani Sim on roaming in UK some questions?

Tags: uk, international-travel, cellphones, pakistan, roaming

I wanted to ask that if you use a pakistani sim on roaming in UK 
And call a UK number from that Pakistani Sim roaming number what does it show on the UK mubile number that the person is calling from Pakistan or UK ?
And if you call another person on roaming in UK what gets shown on his/her screen ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is really on topic here, but the called party will see your Pakistani number no matter where you are when making the call.